# PlatformException error, Invalid document reference, When attempting to work with Firebase Storage

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I have created a function to work on my app. This function add's the photo from my camera or gallery into the Firebase storage, and into the user collection. Althought I'm receiving a strange error when trying to add the data. I have attempted to pass throught this Exception but the data wasn't added neither.
The erro:
[image: Error]

This is the function:

```
class Product {
  final Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;

  final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

  DocumentReference get firestoreRef => firestore.document('products/$id');

  StorageReference get storageRef => storage.ref().child('products').child(id);

  Future<void> save() async {
    loading = true;

    final Map<String, dynamic> data = {
      'name': name,
      'description': description,
      'sizes': exportSizeList()
    };

    if (id == null) {
      final doc = await firestore.collection('products').add(data);
      id = doc.documentID;
    } else {
      await firestoreRef.updateData(data);
    }

    final List<String> updateImages = [];

    for (final newImage in newImages!) {
      if (images.contains(newImage)) {
        updateImages.add(newImage as String);
      } else {
        final StorageUploadTask task =
            storageRef.child(Uuid().v1()).putFile(newImage as File);
        final StorageTaskSnapshot snapshot = await task.onComplete;
        final String url = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL() as String;
        updateImages.add(url);
      }
    }

    for (final image in images) {
      if (!newImages!.contains(image)) {
        try {
          final ref = await storage.getReferenceFromUrl(image);
          await ref.delete();
        } catch (e) {
          debugPrint('Falha ao deletar $image');
        }
      }
    }

    await firestoreRef.updateData({'images': updateImages});

    images = updateImages;

    loading = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the error message is looks like `id` doesn't have a value in this call:

```
firestore.document('products/$id');
```

When `id` has no value, that leads to a document reference with a path `/products/`, which explains the error message.

So you'll want to run the code in a debugger, set a breakpoint on that line, and figure out why `id` doesn't have a value at that point.